# Retrieve matching data twice from same LEFT JOIN table?

Tags: mysql, left-join

**Information**

Is there a way that I can retrieve two bits of information from another(same) table twice in one LEFT JOIN?

**Attempt**

Below is the SQL query I tried to put together in hopes would work. I hope you can see what I am trying to do from it.

`SELECT cards.*, list.name FROM cards 
LEFT JOIN list ON cards.main = list.id AS main_name 
AND cards.enemy = list.id AS enemy_name
WHERE cards.id = 1`

As you can see above I am trying to retrieve the names of two values `cards.main` AND `cards.enemy` from the `list` table.

Thank you, and any questions will be answered asap!

Comment: SELECT cards.main, cards.enemy should do, right?

Comment: The data in cards.main & cards.enemy are ID's, which then I am trying to get their actual name by LEFT JOIN'ing the table list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join the list-table twice:

```
SELECT cards.*, main_name.name, enemy_name.name 
FROM cards 
LEFT JOIN list AS main_name ON cards.main = main_name.id
LEFT JOIN list AS enemy_name ON cards.enemy = enemy_name.id
WHERE cards.id = 1
```

Comment: Is there no way to do it in one join?

Comment: No, those are different rows in the list-table and therefore different joins. Why would you have one join?

Comment: Although you can do ' ON cards.main = list.name OR cards.enemy = list.name' but that would give you two rows in your resultset

Comment: Okay thanks but your code is printing out an error ` #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS main_name LEFT JOIN list ON cards.enemy = list.id AS enemy_' at line 3`

Comment: Managed to solve it by adding alias for the tables then renameing them in the SELECT :)

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. First AS, then ON. I shall also edit the answer.